# How to set the source of a CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs

I'm trying to create a little tool for Microsofts Team Founation Server (which is not that important for the question). However i'm not that familiar with C# and WPF and even after reading through some tutorials about bindings and resources, i can't figure out, how to get the code working.
With the Visual Studio Designer i created a little form, that just has some buttons and a textbox that should display the name of the authorized user. 
Unfortunately, after logging in, an `ArgumentException` is thrown. So the question is : How can i bind my local `TfsTeamProjectCollection` to `tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource`?
Thanks for your help!

```
<Window
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TFSBranchingTool"
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
       xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"

       xmlns:Client="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client" x:Class="TFSBranchingTool.MainWindow"

       mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="TFSBranchingTool" Height="360" Width="560"
       x:Name="wnd" Loaded="wnd_Loaded">
   <Window.Resources>
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Client:TfsTeamProjectCollection}, CreateList=True}" Source="{Binding}"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-1">
       <Menu x:Name="menu" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBrushKey}}" d:IsLocked="True">
           <MenuItem Header="File">
               <MenuItem Header="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="exit_application_click"/>
           </MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Team">
               <MenuItem Header="Connect to server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Width="201" Click="connect_to_server_click"/>
           </MenuItem>
       </Menu>
       <StatusBar x:Name="statusbar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-2" MinHeight="16">
           <StatusBarItem x:Name="connection_status" Content="{Binding TeamProjectCollection.AuthorizedIdentity.DisplayName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
       </StatusBar>
       <Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Label Content="Display Name:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           <TextBox x:Name="displayNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding AuthorizedIdentity.DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
       </Grid>
   </Grid>
```

And here is the logic:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.Windows;

namespace TFSBranchingTool
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TfsTeamProjectCollection m_tfs_team_project_collection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exit_application_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void connect_to_server_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TeamProjectPicker team_project_picker = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.NoProject, false);
            if (team_project_picker.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                m_tfs_team_project_collection = team_project_picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;

                System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource")));

                //ArgumentException : 
                //Additional Information: "<TFS-URI>" is an invalid value for the property "Source".

                tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource.Source = m_tfs_team_project_collection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GetDefaultView` static Method of `CollectionViewSource` class to give the view your collection.

Here is what you have to do.

```
tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource.Source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_tfs_team_project_collection);
```

Also you haven't set the data context of the window as Window itself.

Try doing this.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

By doing the above, any binding in the xaml code will look for its source in the window.

Another thing I have found wrong in your code is that you have defined
`tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource` as a local variable rather than a data member of the Window.

Try making it a data member like `m_tfs_team_project_collection` and then see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The good thing is : it does not crash anymore, the bad thing is : the textbox does not show anything, although i successfully logged in.

Comment: Where is AuthorizedIdentity variable in your code behind ? I don't see it being set and notifying the targets that it has changed through NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Also you haven't set any data context for your xaml as well. Do you know of these concepts ?

Comment: Yes, i read about them. 1. The AuthorizedIdentity is a Property of the TfsTeamProjectCollection, a third-party class from Microsoft. 2. You are right, when i set the DataContext of `grid1` to `m_tfs_team_project_collection` in the code, the value is correctly shown. However, the datacontext of grid1 is already set via the xaml code, `tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource` has no DataContext-Property and when i set the DataContext of the Window, nothing is shown either. Where should i set it?

Comment: Still no luck. The `tfsTeamProjectCollectionViewSource`is, what the designer generated, when i dragged the DisplayName-Property onto the frame. I don't know, what i should do with it, but i thought, it could not be wrong. Anyway, i think, that it is indeed easier to set the data source by hand, without that fancy `CollectionViewSource`-resource-stuff.

Comment: CollectionViewSource provides you the flexibility for sorting and filtering your collection without doing the actual filtering and sorting on collection itself. Take it as an image of your collection, but sorted and filtered according to criteria you set in your filter method of ICollectionView type property. If filtering and sorting is not the requirement than I suggest you bind the collection directly.